# Sticky ad and change position when it reaches a specific div class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to change position back to static after it reaches a specif div class but I'm having issues with it.

this is my jquery so far

```
var elementPosition = $('#stickyad').offset();

$(window).scroll(function(){
    if($(window).scrollTop() > elementPosition.top){
          $('#stickyad').css('position','fixed').css('top','70px');
    } else {
        $('#stickyad').css('position','static');
    } 
});
```

any help would be appreciated

Comment: This seems to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/opnd4jn6/ Do you have a specific problem with it?

Comment: Yes this works fine however what I want to achieve is that as soon as it reaches a certain div class within the page it stops from being fixed and it stops